# Installing specific laravel version with composer create-project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

The fastest and simplest way of installing Laravel is via composer command. From the laravel docs (http://laravel.com/docs/quick), it shows that we can install it with this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

But, when you run the above command, it will grab the latest version of Laravel. How can I control it if I want to install latest version of 4.0.x? Or, 4.1.x when 4.2 is out?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

From the `composer help create-project` command

> The create-project command creates a new project from a given
>   package into a new directory. If executed without params and in a
>   directory                 with a composer.json file it installs the
>   packages for the current project.
>                                                                                                You can use this command to bootstrap new projects or setup a clean
>   version-controlled installation for developers of your project.
>
> **[version]
>
>                                                                                                You can also specify the version with the package name using = or : as
>   separator.**
>                                                                                                To install unstable packages, either specify the version you want, or
>   use the               --stability=dev (where dev can be one of RC,
>   beta, alpha or dev).

This command works:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.1.27 your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

This works with the * notation.

Comment: To play with the dev version (laravel 5): `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name dev-develop`

Comment: I tried `laravel/laravel=5.8.38` which is a perfectly valid version and got `Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.8.38`. I dropped `.38` and it went through.

Comment: @sinaza I think there is no published version called 5.8.38, the latest 5.8 I see is 5.8.35 : https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel#v5.8.35

Comment: you can also add ^ to the version so that the installer will install any latest version for example for version 8, which in this time of writing is 8.6.12
`composer create-project laravel/laravel=^8 your-project-name --prefer-dist`

Answer (score 18):

Try via Composer Create-Project

You may also install Laravel by issuing the Composer create-project command in your terminal:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} "5.0.*" --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 15):

Have a look:

[Laravel 4.2 Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#install-laravel)

**Syntax (Via Composer):**

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

**Example:**

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel my_laravel_dir 4.2
```

Where 4.2 is your version of laravel.

Note: It will take the latest version of Laravel automatically If you will not provide any version.

Comment: and for laravel 5.5: composer create-project laravel/laravel my_laravel_dir 5.5*

Answer (score 6):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.1.27 your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

And then you probably need to install all of vendor packages, so

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a stable version of your preferred Laravel version of choice, use:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project-name "5.5.*"
```

That will pick out the most recent or best update of version 5.5.* (5.5.28)

Answer (score 4):

To install specific version of laravel try this & simply command on terminal

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:5.5.0 {dir-name}
```

Answer (score 3):

Installing specific laravel version with composer create-project

> composer global require laravel/installer

Then, if you want install specific version then just edit version values "6.*" , "5.8.*"

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel Projectname "6.*"

Run Local Development Server

> php artisan serve