# How to install Laravel 4 using composer

Tags: laravel, installation

When laravel 5 is not yet released, I install Laravel 4 using this command `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist`. But now when I use it, It installs laravel 5. I just want to use laravel 4, not yet ready for 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've  tried the other answers but doesn't work for me. So here's the command I use.

`composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.1.27 your-project-name --prefer-dist`

Source : 
[Installing specific laravel version with composer create-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754260/installing-specific-laravel-version-via-composer-create-project)

**UPDATE**

Laravel updated the installation docs of 4.* after releasing 5.

`composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist`

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2#install-laravel

Answer (score 2):

If nothing specified `composer create-project` will get the latest stable version. You can change that by just specifying the version you want:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name ~4.2.0 --prefer-dist
```

This will install the latest `4.2.*` version of laravel

Answer (score 1):

You should download latest laravel 4.2 release from github - https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases/tag/v4.2.11 
then use `composer update` to download all relevant packages including latest laravel version

Answer (score 0):

I use Alternate Method.

Docs says Alternate Method

Once Composer is installed, download the 4.2 version https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/v4.2.11.zip of the Laravel framework and extract its contents into a directory on your server. Next, in the root of your Laravel application, run the php composer.phar install (or composer install) command to install all of the framework's dependencies. This process requires Git to be installed on the server to successfully complete the installation.

If you want to update the Laravel framework, you may issue the php composer.phar update command.

Answer (score -3):

U can use this

composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist

replacing {directory} with the actual directory of your project