# How to choose version of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I was using laravel 4 and due to a error on my computer I had to uninstall it ,I wanted to reinstall version 4.2 but it keeps installing version 5

`composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} --prefer-dist 4.2`

any help would be appreciated ,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`composer create-project laravel/laravel=4.2 {directory} --prefer-dist`

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754260/installing-specific-laravel-version-via-composer-create-project).