# create laravel project with laravel installer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am new to laravel framework,after some search I decided to use laravel 5.1

I read the official document and set the environment,also I install the laravel installer.but when I use laravel installer to create a project, it will use laravel newest version(such as 5.2.*).I want to know how can I specify the laravel version useing laravel installer?

I know I can specify laravel version using **composer create-project ...**,but for some reason when I using composer I must wait for long time.so is there a way useing laravel installer to create project with specified laravel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing specific laravel version with composer create-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754260/installing-specific-laravel-version-with-composer-create-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it using this alternative [laravel installer](https://github.com/artesaos/laravel-installer).

```
composer g require artesaos/laravel-installer
```

And then you can do:

```
laravel new name version
```

You may need to uninstall the previous installer you had.