# Installing Laravel with Composer create-project - how to use the newest version?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-7

It has been a while since I created a new project with Laravel framework. Decided to install a fresh project so opened up V7 documentation at [Install Via Composer Create-Project](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#installing-laravel).

First updated my global Composer installation to the newest version: `composer self-update`

Then ran installation with **composer create-project** as exampled in the docs: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myproject`

After installation went into the directory to check Laravel's version: `cd myproject && php laravel -V`

Much to my surprise it had installed a much older version: `Laravel Framework 5.8.37`

Expected to get the newest version... **Why did it install an older version, and how do I upgrade or instruct the create-project command to use the newest version?**

Comment: composer create-project laravel/laravel=YOUR_VERSION your-project-name --prefer-dist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific laravel version with composer create-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754260/installing-specific-laravel-version-with-composer-create-project)

Comment: Sorry but that question has different problem, as "when you run the above command, it will grab the latest version of Laravel." – I have the opposite situation, as I was expecting to get the newest version but got a really old one.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Tried to see what global composer packages was installed but there was no global Laravel package installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks lile your environment is insufficient for L7 (like too old PHP version, missing required extensions etc). You should ensure your environment fulfills Laravel requirements:

- PHP >= 7.2.5
- BCMath PHP Extension
- Ctype PHP Extension
- Fileinfo PHP extension
- JSON PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
  Tokenizer PHP Extension
  XML PHP Extension

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#server-requirements

Also keep in mind that php-cli version you use may be different from what your httpd is using (i. e. due to `$PATH` and multiple PHP versions are installed).

Comment: I ran that installation command in my OSX terminal with PHP 7.1... Went on to use Laravel installer from inside Homestead which gave me Laravel 7.4.0.

Comment: If I use `composer create-project` inside Homestead 9.4.0 box it outputs "Installing laravel/laravel (v7.3.0)", however, after the installation `php artisan -V` gives me 7.4.0 and not 7.3.0 as first outputted.

Comment: L7 requires PHP 7.2+ which you do not have

Comment: That must be it then... I'd expect to Composer to notify of installation requirements having not been met and falling back to an older version.

Comment: It would only in case of missing requirements. For now it managed to figure out which L version would work on your setup. And as you did not specify exact version then it took the latest that fits