# why don't install laravel lates version

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-8

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel testlaraval

i use this command but it install laraval

```
- Installing laravel/laravel (v6.18.35): Extracting archive
```

i need laraval 8.5

after that i used

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel livemart 8.5.
```

but it showed this,

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 8 in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing specific laravel version with composer create-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754260/installing-specific-laravel-version-with-composer-create-project)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using on your command line?

Comment: PHP 7.2.4 (cli) (built: Mar 28 2018 04:27:01) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Comment: Laravel 8 requires [PHP >= 7.3](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#server-requirements), Laravel 7 requires [PHP >= 7.2.5](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#server-requirements). Therefore the latest version of Laravel that you can use is 6.

Comment: Thanks @aynber. fixed it